# Java check platform supports sctp otherwise use tcp

Tags: java-8, netty, sctp

Because `netty` uses different channel initialization for SCTP and TCP, so I would like to check if the platform supports SCTP, if it does, uses SCTP otherwise uses TCP. However, I could not find any method to check this in both JDK8 or netty4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to call `com.sun.nio.sctp.SctpServerChannel` without an exception if sctp is available but I can't confirm that because I support sctp on all my devices.

[Openjdk SCTP guide](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/sctp/html/gettingstarted.html)

> To ensure that you have a correctly configured machine and JDK, try compiling and running the following application:

```
public class TestSCTP
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        com.sun.nio.sctp.SctpChannel sc = com.sun.nio.sctp.SctpChannel.open();
    }
}

$ jdk1.7.0/bin/javac TestSCTP.java
$ jdk1.7.0/bin/java TestSCTP
```

> If it compiles and runs without any errors, then congratulations you have a correctly configured machine and JDK. You can now start writing applications that use the SCTP API.

Comment: If doing this check from a program, make sure to close the channel after a success check, else you leak 1 of your file descriptors